# Print specific array value after query in php yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

In my *yii2* project I wrote query:

```
$Result = $query->select(['LT.Title','L.Balance', 'L.Earned'])->where(['L.EmployeeID'=>Yii::$app->user->id])->from('leave L')->leftJoin('listitems LT','LT.ListItemID = L.LeaveTypeID')->all();
```

and get result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Title] => sick
        [Balance] => 12
        [Earned] => 12
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [Title] => casual
        [Balance] => 12
        [Earned] => 12
    )

)
```

the result is as I expected;

How can I print a single value like Title, Balance, Earned?

I tried using foreach loop but I am unable to get the result and get error `Trying to get property of non-object` instead.

Comment: your result is array not activerecord object, i guess. In foreach try `$value['Title'];`

Comment: Show your foreach loop code.

Comment: Yes i got it thanks

Comment: <?php foreach ($Result as $key => $Res) {
     echo "<div class='col-lg-4'>
        <div class='well'>".$Res->Title."
        <p>".$Res->Earned."</p>
        <p>".$Res->Balance."</p>
        </div>
       </div>";
     }
    ?> 
I did this previously

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($Result as $key => $Res) {
                echo "<div class='col-lg-4'>
                            <div class='well'>".$Res['Title']."
                            <p>".$Res['Earned']."</p>
                            <p>".$Res['Balance']."</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>";
                }
            ?>
```

Doing This simply i am able to get what i wanted to .